Was VBT able to explain some of the unrealistic implications of hybridisation?
A theory is a possible explanation of reality, i.e., it explains why we observe what we observe by predicting what might be happening behind the scenes. Until we obtain a result that cannot be explained by the theory, the theory is a valid explanation of what might be happening in reality. Once a theory is disproved it can either become a model (like hybridisation) if it is useful, i.e., it has significant predictive power in a particular niche of science or, it is completely disposed of (correct me if I'm wrong).
Now keeping this in mind and coming to my question, while I was studying hybridisation I came across many absurd implications of the theory. My question is how did hybridisation explain these implications, or was it unable to do so? The implications are:
1)According to hybridisation, before bonding takes place the orbitals within the central atom combine to form a set of hybrid orbitals which all have the same energy and shape. During chemical reactions old bonds are broken and new ones are formed, thus the hybridisation of the atom is bound to change. My question is how does the hybridisation actually change? The only way (I believe) the hybridisation of an atom can change is by taking back all the hybrid orbitals converting them back into pure orbitals and remixing them again, which sounds too impractical to be true.
2)How does an atom know when to hybridise? I do understand that hybridisation is energetically favourable for the system so that serves as a driving force for the process to occur, but how exactly does the atom know when to hybridise?
I do realise that theories on quantum particles are extremely hypothetical due to our limited access to "the quantum world" and as such we need to rely largely on our intuition and experimental evidence to develop theories. But, this does not necessarily mean that what we theorize is wrong, it just means there is a higher probability of it being wrong (again, correct me if I'm wrong).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@Mayo Sorry, but I'm not voting to reopen something that asks "How does an atom know" anything, because it doesn't. You simple don't get hybridisation! That's the issue, so maybe just read about it in some serious source?

I'll just remove that part since buck Thorne already answered that for me

VBT uses a basis set that resembles bond orbitals. These bond orbitals are mathematically described as hybrid orbitals.  Hybridisation doesn't happen, it's one mathematical way to describe a wave function. Your point 1 is void. Most importantly: hybridisation has no effect on energy. Your assumption 2 is completely wrong.
